# Best practice to resolve "Implied default locale in case conversion" Android lint warning

Tags: java, android, lint

I have an Android app that should always use the `Locale.US` locale, and I started running Lint checks. One warning popping up is "Implied default locale in case conversion", which happens whenever I call `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` on a string.

What is the best way to generate these strings, ensuring it always uses the correct `Locale`? I don't want to pass it in every time I call `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either pass it every time, or make a convenience method that passes it and call that instead.

Comment: Is there a way to set the default once, so that I don't need to pass it in every time or create a new convenience method? I don't know if Android allows me to do that.

Comment: If you use the 0 parameter one it uses your default locale. But then it will always warn you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a String that user can see then you should use the `Locale.getDefault()` since some characters get replaced in certain languages. For instance the `i` in turkish.

If it's a 'developer' String (backend constant, string type etc) that you'll only youse internaly, you will want to use `Locale.US`.